# Why does my Cycles-X render look different when saved as a png?

Tags: rendering

[image: rendered]
Here's how it looks after rendering

[image: saved]
Here's the result after saving as a png

Any idea why it looks so different?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have Save As Render checked in the save dialog so the image goes through color management. Else than that, you are using an experimental unreleased version, so... That's to be expected. Maybe report it as a bug after checking if it's not fixed in today's build or already reported.

[image]

Comment: this helped. i think my problem was that there was emissions with large valuels. it's really jarring to take the render result image, save it, and open that same image in the built in image viewer, seeing a totally differently lit picture